# How to call CQ author URL from a standalone code

Tags: aem, sling

I am trying to hit URL in cq Author instance from my standalone code. The URL looks like — `http://<somehost>:<someport>//libs/dam/gui/content/reports/export.json`

Below is the code:

```
URL url = new URL(newPath);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setReadTimeout(15 * 10000);
connection.connect();

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

But I got a 401 error, which is expected, as I'm not passing any authentication information — hence Sling says:

> getAnonymousResolver: Anonymous access not allowed by configuration - requesting credentials.

How can I get resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You may use Basic HTTP authentication. Adding it to the `HttpURLConnection` is little awkward:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

Consider using [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html):

```
UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin");
DefaultHttpClient authorizedClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
request.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, request));
HttpResponse response = authorizedClient.execute(request);
InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```